# Azure-Function: Import JSON Webhook to SQL

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to implement a version of:
    http://sqlblog.com/blogs/davide_mauri/archive/2017/02/05/azure-functions-dapper-and-sql-server-json-to-store-form-data.aspx

However I am getting error:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.Incoming. System.Net.Http.Formatting: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JObject' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.

The Function in run.csx is:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using Dapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    JObject contactFormData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>();

    string azureSQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"]?.ConnectionString;

    string payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contactFormData);

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(azureSQLConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Execute("dbo.incomingSP", new { payload = payload }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);                
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I also have a project.json file as:

```
    {
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Dapper": "1.42.0",
        "System.Data.SqlClient":"4.1.0",
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager":"3.2.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

And my test JSON code is:

```
{
    "transaction": 
    {
        "IP": "7797",
        "Time": "2017-01-01"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your request has `application/octet-stream` encoding. Try changing it to `application/json`?

Comment: We are capturing logs from modsecurity.  I'm not sure there is any way to change the request headers unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message I think the client sends data as file. In this case you should read the request content as binary and then convert to a string. Since you don't need JSON in the body of the funtion itself, you can also skip the deserialization/serialization and pass the payload directly into SQL:

```
var bytes = await req.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); 
var payload = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes); 
// Uncomment to trace your payload: 
// log.Info(payload);
```

Then use `payload` in your SQL call as you already do.

Comment: You can replicate the error using the 'test' JSON in the question.  Simply add that to the test section in the Azure Function and it gives the same error.  You don't need to submit an external request to get the error.  Even if I change the Request Headers to application/JSON in the test function it still gives the error.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and sample, and it works fine with Test button in the portal.

Comment: Interesting.  What template type did you use?

Comment: C# HTTP trigger. Btw, why do you need to convert to `JObject` and then back to `string`? Just do `string payload = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.

Comment: Ha!  When I created a new function using the code in the question it works perfectly.  Strange.  There must be a problem with the settings for the old function that prevented it from working...

Comment: The 'code' paramater was missing it looks like: {
"Message": "The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter."
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140222/discussion-between-mikhail-and-marcus).